# RegEx to select a space between two digits

Tags: regex

Given a string as the following, containing only `0` and `1` separated by spaces with an additional space at the end of each line.
I want to select only the spaces between the digits but not the one at the end of the line to search and replace them with `,`.
When I try to create a RegEx I either select all spaces or the surrounding digits too.

```
GIVEN      WANTED     NOT WANTED     TOTALLY NOT WANTED
0 1 0 1    0,1,0,1    0,1,0,1,       ,,,,
0 0 1 0    0,0,1,0    0,0,1,0,       ,,,,
1 0 1 0    1,0,1,0    1,0,1,0,       ,,,,
1 1 0 0    1,1,0,0    1,1,0,0,       ,,,,
1 1 1 0    1,1,1,0    1,1,1,0,       ,,,,
1 1 0 0    1,1,0,0    1,1,0,0,       ,,,,
```

So, how can I only select those spaces that have a digit on both sides, but not the digits. Is there some kind of syntax feature that matches but does not select?

**Working answers:**
As multiple answers were correct I want to collect them here. The accepted answer is the first one because it is the shortest regex and completely does what is needed.

`(?!$)` - please note there is a `space` at the beginning of this regex.

`(?<=\d)\s(?=\d)` or `(?<=[01])\s(?=[01])` if your digits are either 0 or 1

Comment: What RegEx were you trying before?

Comment: I tried a Regex like `[01][" "][01]`. I am using Java but I am trying the search and replace in notepad++.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you're sure that your text contains only `1` and `0` you can use this

regex `(?!$)` there is a  `space` character at the beginning of regex

check this [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yK9eZ7/1)

and if you're not sure you can use this one `(?<=\d) (?=\d)` but this is going to work only if look ahead and look behind is supported , I don't know which language  you're using exactly , this is `PERL` regex

check the [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yK9eZ7/3)

Comment: I accept this answer because it is the shortest regex and in addition it does not need look ahead and look behind.

Comment: you've both options :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following to match just the space between numbers and not the numbers:

```
(?<=\d)\s(?=\d) or (?<=[01])\s(?=[01]) if your digits are either 0 or 1
```

And replace with `,`

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/sW3qN8/5)

Answer (score 0):

To select a group with digits on either side, you can use:

```
\d( )\d
```

Matched group 1 in this case will contain the space. Or you can replace the entire group by capturing both digits and just inserting your comma,

```
(\d) (\d)
```

Extracting groups 1 and 2 and putting a comma between them could work.

Comment: This is actually more complicated than the other answers right now and as I am pretty new to regex I don't know how to extract groups.

Comment: You should use `\s` instead of ` `